# jQuery: how to remember selections in a multi-step Rails 3 form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a multi-step form in Rails 3 using this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

In one of the steps of my form, I can add and remove a group of select boxes. One of these select boxes contains a set of numbers that are added together to produce a sum, as new groups of fields are added. You can see an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/beehive/HGJck/

The problem I'm having is when I go back and forth through the steps in my multi-step form, my selections in this step of the form are not remembered. How can I fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/* Add & Remove */
var removeButton = "<button id='remove'>Remove</button>";
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('div.container:last').after($('div.container:first').clone());
    $('div.container:last').append(removeButton);

    /* Sum */
    $(".number").change(function() {
        var combined = -10;
        $(".number").each(function() {
            combined += parseInt(this.value);
        });
        $("#sum").html(combined);
    }).trigger("change"); 

    return false;

});

$('#remove').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div.container').remove();
});

});​
```

Comment: You could store it in cookies, session or viewport

Comment: everything is currently stored in a session. I've been thinking that I might have to move a portion of the code into a function? Don't know.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way could be as you go back or forth ,keep the whole html of this control in a variable and persist that html with different steps and when you come back to this page restore the html from that variable.
Please let me know if any issue